# Can I specify a custom color (e.g., RGB) for Alloy Analyzer to use in visualizations?

Tags: visualization, alloy

In the theme pane, I'd love to get rid of the barely-readable yellow and replace it with an orange and maybe swap the red for a darker red.

Is there an XML (or some kind of easily-editable config file) in the Alloy build that defines something like RGB values that show in the Alloy visualizer theme selections? Or some other way to accomplish a change in what's available in the drop-down menu without too much effort?

I'm trying to avoid doing a deep dive into the repo and associated documentation if I can help it.

I have a series of modules that reuse certain signatures and relations and I'd like to keep my color scheme as consistent as possible, so Magic Layout won't really work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried switching colors schemes?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I did. The "Standard" palette was the most readable across the palette, IMO, but still not quite what I was looking for. I was really hoping to specify a custom palette.